# Javascript: object['name'] issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I had an object of the form `obj[prop]` and in the case where `prop === 'name'`, using the syntax `obj[prop] = 'xyz'` was failing to set the property. Insteadm I had to delete `obj[prop]` first and then set it.

The code is far too much to put down here so this is a general question. Does anybody have an idea what might cause this problem? This was ONLY happening when prop === 'name'. Every other property I tried had no issues.

Comment: if u are using a obj, not an array type, you can make use of the function obj,hasOwnProperty(propertyname) this will return a true or false

Comment: What is `obj`? Where is it created? is it possible that `name` is defined with a getter/setter? To check this, place a breakpoint at the `obj[prop] = 'xyz';` line, and trace into the code; it may take you inside a setter for this property.

Comment: I couldnt find any changes to the definition. Im going to guess that using JSON parse is causing some funkiness somewhere. Just going to use delete before setting the property.

Comment: Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 2):

I know of only one such circumstance: `name` being defined as not writable. It also has to be configurable, otherwise you wouldn't have been able to delete it.

```
var prince = {}
Object.defineProperty(prince, 'name', {
  writable: false,
  configurable: true,
  value: "Prince"
})
prince.name = 'The Artist Formerly Known as Prince';
console.log(prince.name);
// => Prince
```

Comment: Wouldn't it also be possible that `name` is defined with a getter/setter?

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the property "name" is writable :

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'name');
> Object {value: "xyz", writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
```

More information about property descriptors here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor#Description

Comment: Thankyou I was just looking for the dump for the property!

Comment: Everything is the basic setup. I cannot recreate the issue either in jsFiddle. Might just have to bite the bullet and ignore the error :(

Comment: This is strange... You can also look into the "freeze/isFrozen", "seal/isSealed" and "preventExtension/isExtensible" methods of the Object constructor. They can make an object immutable and things like that. I don't know these methods that well, so here is the documentation:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor

Comment: If the object was frozen or sealed, he wouldn't be able to delete the property. `preventExtensions` would still let him change the property.